# What is the maximum allowed number of TTY, is it defined anywhere in kernel headers?

Tags: linux, kernel, tty, pty

What's the maximum allowed number of TTYs?

I found pty.max, but is there anything similar for TTYs? Or is it defined as a fixed value in kernel headers, I couldn't find that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you're referring Linux virtual consoles as TTYs, their number by default is 64 and this is defined in `include/uapi/linux/vt.h` inside the Linux kernel source tree. The thing you're looking for is `NR_CONSOLES`.

Comment: Does it apply to TTYs? pty is configurable

Comment: Thanks Sami, I still want to know where the `64` is defined

Comment: @RubanSavvy please read the greyed text in the textarea, it is there before you start typing. Voting is good, commenting on that you have done so superfluous.